# PHP turning json into array

Tags: php, json, foreach

So I've got this huge amount of data in a php-file but it is in json-format.

I have tried converting it putting all the json into one $string variable.
Then:

```
$json = json_decode($string);

foreach($json as $key => $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

This doesn't work though so I'm woundering how I can put all this data into a mysql-database instead (or arrays).

This is a small part of the data.

```
[{
"namn":"ABF VUX",
"schoolID":"85740",
"stad":"G\u00f6teborg",
"PeriodDropDownList":false,
"FreeTextBox":false,
"code":"680378",
"lan":"V\u00e4stra G\u00f6talands l\u00e4n",
"WeekDropDownList":true,
"TypeDropDownList":true,
"startTid":"-"
},
{
"namn":"Adolf Fredriks Musikklasser",
"schoolID":"29320",
"stad":"Stockholm",
"PeriodDropDownList":true,
"FreeTextBox":true,
"code":"",
"lan":"Stockholms l\u00e4n",
"WeekDropDownList":true,
"TypeDropDownList":true,
"startTid":"8:15"
}]
```

Comment: how are you opening the file, show that part....

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* -- well, what did you expect to happen, and what actually happened? Please provide enough info to actually answer the question.

Comment: also....if its php in the first place, doesn't that mean it was an array at one point in the cycle....surely before it gets encoded to json, you can upload? no? Am I missing something.  Why have another file that decodes it and uploads?

Comment: Also, is your question "how do I turn it into an array" (the title) or "how do I put it into mysql" (in the question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the exact json, but your example code generates an array of objects so that is why `echo` does not work.

What should work with your example, is something like:

```
$json = json_decode($string);

foreach($json as $key => $value) {
  echo $value->namn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```

This should make `$json` an associative array.